# How to replace a directory using QGIS Field calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, sql

I have a column called Hotlink full of incorrect directories and I need to edit them.

They currently read C:/ABCD/filename.pdf and I want them to read C:/Maps/ABCD/ABCD/filename.pdf

The script I'm trying to use but not having much luck with is as follows:
replace
 ("Hotlink", '(ABCD)', '(Maps/ABCD/ABCD)');

How can I get this to work?

Comment: maybe try replace ("Hotlink" , 'ABCD' , 'Maps/ABCD/ABCD')

Comment: I still get the errors, Parser Error: syntax error, unexpected Unknown_CHARACTER, expecting $endEval and Error:
No root node! Parsing failed? Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: it may not like those / characters... let me do a little research, its been awhile since i used qgis

Comment: try this replace ("Hotlink" , 'ABCD' , 'Maps\\ABCD\\ABCD')    see https://www.esdm.co.uk/qgis-field-calculator-backslash-gotcha

Comment: That works! I appreciate all your help!

Comment: I posted the answer below, if you can mark it correct when you can so others know we have the solution =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we have a definite answer to the question:

The problem involves QGIS not liking the backslash

try this

`replace ("Hotlink" , 'ABCD' , 'Maps\\ABCD\\ABCD')`

see esdm.co.uk/qgis-field-calculator-backslash-gotcha

Comment: `replace ( "Hotlink" , 'ABCD', 'Maps/ABCD/ABCD')` and  `replace ("Hotlink", '(ABCD)', '(Maps/ABCD/ABCD)')` works for me. The solution of ed.hankins is for Windows paths. Here Paul use the Unix path.