# "\"-character is not recognized in field calculator string (URL field)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, url

I have this irritating problem with "\" symbol in field calculator in QGIS. I'm trying to insert an URL field in order to open feature specific pictures later as an action, but as I insert the symbol in question, it is not recognized. See below. Preview will be the result if I hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

Column's data type is text and layer is UTF8 encoded. I'm using QGIS 3.2.0 on Windows 10.

It's a small issue, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Did you try the concat function(under String operations)?
example:
concat( 'Turku','/','2018')

Comment: @TarasDubrava Your answer seems to be correct. Can you elaborate why double symbol is needed? If there's no duplicate question for this, you could post an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263211/using-qgis-field-calculator-to-replace-backslash

Comment: I assume moderators have/will check if this is a duplicate without informing them separately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I could assume that you are working on Windows OS, is not it?

Therefore, it requires doubled backslashes **`\\`**.

---

**References:**

- [Using QGIS Field Calculator to replace backslash?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263211/using-qgis-field-calculator-to-replace-backslash)
- [How to replace a directory using QGIS Field calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178932/how-to-replace-a-directory-using-qgis-field-calculator)
- [QGIS field calculator backslash gotcha](https://www.esdm.co.uk/qgis-field-calculator-backslash-gotcha)
- [python replace single backslash with double backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327202/python-replace-single-backslash-with-double-backslash/39847354)

Comment: Yes, on windows 10. Edited my question. Cheers Taras!